# How do I loop my python code a specific number of times?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I've been struggling to loop my code a specific number of times. I've YouTubed mulitple videos on while statements for looping but it never works. I have gotten to a point where I managed to run the code but then once it ran once it started looping and listing number 1 - 10. I'm assuming this is because I specified <10 to loop. I don't think I'm understanding but I am a visual learner and the text examples aren't helping. Here's the code I would like to loop.

```
import urllib.request
import os



urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://websitewithimageonit.com/", "")

i = 0
while os.path.exists("image%s.jpg" % i):
    i += 1

fh = open("image%s.jpg" % i, "w")
```

I tried to do it myself and used a while loop like this below. The code ran, saved 1 image but then just listed 1 - 10 in the PyCharm console.

```
import urllib.request
import os
import time

urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://websitewithimageonit.com/", "")

i = 0
while os.path.exists("image%s.jpg" % i):
    i += 1

fh = open("image%s.jpg" % i, "w")
 

condition = 1
while condition < 10:
    print(condition)
    condition += 1
```

After it runs the code it prints this in the console

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Which I'm assuming is me messing up the while loop. Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: The code you want to repeat needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: Any code that you want to repeat must be inside the loop. Currently, the only code inside the last loop is `print(condition)` and `condition += 1`, so those are the only things that repeat.

Comment: I don't understand how to put the code inside the loop. Can you point me to some resource or a code example please.

Comment: Please, start with the basics https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=control%20flow and remember that indentation counts in python https://www.askpython.com/python/python-indentation

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to do something like:

```
i = 0
while os.path.exists(f"image{i}.jpg"):
    with open(f"image{i}.jpg", "w") as fh:
        #do stuff with the file here

    #do other stuff here

    #at the end of the loop, increment i
    i += 1
```

Read the following for more info

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/

Comment: what is your expected output? please provide a minimal reproducible example, else it will be impossible for us to help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just want to loop this code a specific number of times e.g. 10. The code opens a website, saves the image. The code by itself works great but it only runs once. I tried to add a loop but I can't get it to work and the code here isn't helping me understand. I'm not a programmer this is just for a specific task. 

import urllib.request
import os
import time


urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://websitewithimage/", "")

i = 0
while os.path.exists("image%s.jpg" % i):
    i += 1

fh = open("image%s.jpg" % i, "w")

Answer (score 0):

You can combine for loop with range function
so if you want to do 50 times something here is the loop

```
for times in range(50):
    print("x")
```

Comment: what is the print("x") ? i dont know how to interpret this

Comment: print("x") is uselles you can do anything instead of print("x")

Comment: in your case you wanted to print(condition):condition = 1
while condition < 10:
    print(condition)
    condition += 1

Comment: instead you can make: for times in range(10):print(times + 1) than it will print number untill 11

Comment: So how do I learn to write the proper code? like this:

import urllib.request
import os

for times in range(50):
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://randomsite.com/", "")

i = 0
while os.path.exists("image%s.jpg" % i):
    i += 1

fh = open("image%s.jpg" % i, "w")

print("x")